# Pillow for kivy-ios use shows "Undefined symbol" error related to little CMS during X-Code build

Tags: python, ios, xcode, kivy, toolchain

I'm trying to use pillow for kivy-ios programming. Following code works fine on Mac with no issue, but when I build on X-Code using toolchain, errors appear like,

Undefined symbol: _cmsCloseProfile
Undefined symbol: _cmsCreateLab2Profile
Undefined symbol: _cmsCreateProofingTransform
Undefined symbol: _cmsCreateTransform
Undefined symbol: _cmsCreateXYZProfile
Undefined symbol: _cmsCreate_sRGBProfile
...

For installation, I did as follows.

- kivy-ios installation
  git clone https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios.git
  cd kivy-ios
  pip install -r requirements.txt
- X-code command line tool installation
  xcode-select --install
- Pillow and dependency installation
  pip install pillow
  brew install libtiff libjpeg webp little-cms2
  brew install autoconf automake libtool pkg-config
  brew link libtool
- Cython installation
  pip install cython==0.28.1
- Toolchain builds
  toolchain build python3 kivy

After "toolchain recipes", I noticed pillow is already in the recipes, so,

toolchain build pillow

Here, I noticed kivy-ios is using Python 3.8 (while my system is using 3.71). I know Python 3.8 needs Pillow 6.2.1 or above, but the Pillow in "toolchain recipes" is 6.1.0. This might be the reason for the error, but I don't know how I can change the Python version for kivy-ios.
(I also tried toolchain pip install pillow==6.2.1, but says "Requirement already satisfied: pillow==6.2.1" when toolchain recipes still says pillow is 6.1.0. Also tried toolchain pip install python==3.8, but showed "ERROR: No matching distribution found for python==3.8".)

Then I created a kivy-ios project.

- Project creation
  toolchain create TestButton Program folder
  open testbutton.xcodeproj

In "Link Binaries with Libraries" of "Build Phases", I can see libpillow.a and libjpeg.a, but no libtiff, webp little-cms2.

Then I tried,
toolchain pip install littlecms
and
toolchain pip install lcms

but both show "ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:" whose error message is hard to understand like,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/users/taka/venv/py37kivy/bin/toolchain", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/taka/venv/py37kivy/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 1519, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/Users/taka/venv/py37kivy/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 1276, in __init__
    getattr(self, args.command)()
  File "/Users/taka/venv/py37kivy/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 1478, in pip
    _pip(sys.argv[2:])
  File "/Users/taka/venv/py37kivy/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 1171, in _pip
    shprint(pip_cmd, *args, _env=pip_env)
  File "/Users/taka/venv/py37kivy/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 55, in shprint
    for line in cmd:
  File "/Users/taka/venv/py37kivy/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 863, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/Users/taka/venv/py37kivy/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 792, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/Users/taka/venv/py37kivy/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /Users/taka/kivy-ios_nopods/dist/hostpython3/bin/pip3 install --isolated --prefix /Users/taka/kivy-ios_nopods/dist/root/python3 lcms

  STDOUT:
Collecting lcms
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d0/b9/90059be08b3b5043c3b81b8ad626068452af3158ab0dc40c3201f053827e/lcms-0.3.0.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/taka/kivy-ios/dist/hostpython3/bin/python3.8 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-yi2ch7vh/lcms/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-yi2ch7vh/lcms/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' --no-user-cfg egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: /private/tmp/pip-install-yi2ch7vh/lcms/
    Complete output (5 lines):
 ... (580 more, please see e.stdout)

  STDERR:
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

- Python code (main.py)

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import StringProperty 
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
import kivy.properties as props
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFilter
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color
RAD_MULT = 0.25

class TextWidget(Widget):
    i = 0
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TextWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    def button_clicked(self):
        self.ids['label1'].text = str(self.i)
        self.i+=1

class TestApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.title = 'greeting'

    def build(self):
        return TextWidget()
    
class MDButton(ButtonBehavior, Label):
    button_pressed_color = 0, 0, 0, 0.3
    button_normal_color = 0.1,0.1,0.1,1
    button_color = button_normal_color
    highlight_textcolor = 0.5,0.5,0,1
    shadow_texture1 = props.ObjectProperty(None)
    shadow_pos1 = props.ListProperty([0, 0])
    shadow_size1 = props.ListProperty([0, 0])

    shadow_texture2 = props.ObjectProperty(None)
    shadow_pos2 = props.ListProperty([0, 0])
    shadow_size2 = props.ListProperty([0, 0])

    elevation = props.NumericProperty(4)
    _shadow_clock = None

    _shadows = {
        1: (1, 3, 0.12, 1, 2, 0.24),
        2: (3, 6, 0.16, 3, 6, 0.23),
        3: (10, 20, 0.19, 6, 6, 0.23),
        4: (14, 28, 0.25, 10, 10, 0.22),
        5: (19, 38, 0.30, 15, 12, 0.22)
    }
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MDButton, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self._update_shadow = Clock.create_trigger(self._create_shadow)

    def on_press(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.orgbutton_color = self.button_color
        self.button_color = self.button_pressed_color
        self.orgbutton_textcolor = self.color
        self._create_rectangle()

    def on_release(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.button_color = self.orgbutton_color
        self.canvas.after.clear()

    def on_size(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._update_shadow()

    def on_pos(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._update_shadow()

    def on_elevation(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._update_shadow()

    def _create_shadow(self, *args):
        ow, oh = self.size[0], self.size[1]

        offset_x = 0

        # Shadow 1
        shadow_data = self._shadows[self.elevation]
        offset_y = shadow_data[0]
        radius = shadow_data[1]
        w, h = ow + radius * 6.0, oh + radius * 6.0
        t1 = self._create_boxshadow(ow, oh, radius, shadow_data[2])
        self.shadow_texture1 = t1
        self.shadow_size1 = w, h
        self.shadow_pos1 = self.x - \
            (w - ow) / 2. + offset_x, self.y - (h - oh) / 2. - offset_y

        # Shadow 2
        shadow_data = self._shadows[self.elevation]
        offset_y = shadow_data[3]
        radius = shadow_data[4]
        w, h = ow + radius * 6.0, oh + radius * 6.0
        t2 = self._create_boxshadow(ow, oh, radius, shadow_data[5])
        self.shadow_texture2 = t2
        self.shadow_size2 = w, h
        self.shadow_pos2 = self.x - \
            (w - ow) / 2. + offset_x, self.y - (h - oh) / 2. - offset_y

    def _create_boxshadow(self, ow, oh, radius, alpha):
        w = ow + radius * 6.0
        h = oh + radius * 6.0
        w = int(w)
        h = int(h)
        texture = Texture.create(size=(w, h), colorfmt='rgba')
        im = Image.new('RGBA', (w, h), color=(1, 1, 1, 0))
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
        x0, y0 = (w - ow) / 2., (h - oh) / 2.
        x1, y1 = x0 + ow - 1, y0 + oh - 1
        draw.rectangle((x0, y0, x1, y1), fill=(0, 0, 0, int(255 * alpha)))
        im = im.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(radius * RAD_MULT))
        texture.blit_buffer(im.tobytes(), colorfmt='rgba', bufferfmt='ubyte')
        return texture

    def _create_rectangle(self):
        with self.canvas.after:
            Color(rgba=[self.button_pressed_color[0], self.button_pressed_color[1],
                        self.button_pressed_color[2], self.button_pressed_color[3]])
            Rectangle(pos=(self.pos[0], self.pos[1]),
                      size=(self.size[0], self.size[1]))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

- kivy code (test.kv)

```
#:kivy 1.0.9

TextWidget:

<TextWidget>:
    label1:label1
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.8,0.8,0.8,1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size: root.size
        padding:25,25,25,25
        spacing:25
        Label:
            id: label1
            font_size: 68
            color:0,0.4,0.4,1
            text: "Hello World"

        MDButton:
            id: button1
            text: "OK"
            font_size: 48
            on_release:root.button_clicked()
<MDButton>:
    ripple_color: 0, 0, 0, .2
    background_color: 1, 1, 1, 1

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,1,1,1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.shadow_size1
            pos: self.shadow_pos1
            texture: self.shadow_texture1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.shadow_size2
            pos: self.shadow_pos2
            texture: self.shadow_texture2
        Color:
            # rgba: 1,1,1,1
            rgba:root.button_color  # visual feedback of press
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
```

Comment: Found an error happens during brew install little-cms2, so uninstalled, re-installed and re-linked. The error message has disappeared!

Comment: i've got the same error as above, however cannot solve even after trying reinstalling little-cms2, pls advise me other ways if possible